# Ui view freez for long time

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am working on afnetworking, i have web service that takes too much time to load data and i want that UI do not freeze, i used this [tutorial](http://jeffreysambells.com/2013/03/01/asynchronous-operations-in-ios-with-grand-central-dispatch) to run webservice on background so that i can work on other views as well, but not sucess till yet.

```
  -(void) getArticles :(NSString*)stateAbbre  completionHandler:(void (^)(id array))success
{

    [MyCommonFunctions showGlobalProgressHUDWithTitle:@"Loading"];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://cloud.ilmasoft.com/depilex/depilexs/get_articles_ios.php"];

    NSLog(@"%@",link);
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
    [manager GET:link parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);


        NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


        NSDictionary *returnedDealDict = responseObject ;
        NSArray *returnArray = [returnedDealDict objectForKey:@"Result"];


        for(NSDictionary *dealDict in returnArray)
        {
            ArticlesDC *articles = [[ArticlesDC alloc] init];
            articles.articlesID = [[dealDict objectForKey:@"id"]intValue ];
            articles.articleTitle = [dealDict objectForKey:@"title" ];
            articles.articleDetail =  [dealDict objectForKey:@"details" ];
            articles.articleDate = [dealDict objectForKey:@"date" ];
            articles.articlePic = [dealDict objectForKey:@"pic" ];
            articles.articleThumbPath = [dealDict objectForKey:@"thumb_path" ];
            articles.articleStatus = [dealDict objectForKey:@"status" ];
            [dataArray addObject:articles];
            [MyCommonFunctions dismissGlobalHUD];
        }

        success(dataArray);

        //        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

        if (dataArray.count == 0)
        {
            ALERT_VIEW(@"Please check your internet connection.");
            //            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        }

    }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
             ALERT_VIEW(@"Error occured while loading data.");
             //             [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
         }];

}
```

and in my view did load method

```
[self getArticles:nil completionHandler:^(id array) {
        articlesArray = array;
        [tblView reloadData];
        for (ArticlesDC *article in articlesArray)
        {

            NSString *stringWithoutSpace = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://cloud.ilmasoft.com/depilex/admin/%@", article.articleThumbPath] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: stringWithoutSpace]];
            UIImage *imgOne = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            NSString *stringforImg = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://cloud.ilmasoft.com/depilex/admin/%@", article.articlePic] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSData *imageDta = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: stringforImg]];
            UIImage *imgTwo = [UIImage imageWithData:imageDta];

            [dbHandler insertArticlesIntoSqlite:article.articleTitle andDetail:article.articleDetail anddate:article.articleDate andImage:[MyCommonFunctions saveImageInDocuments:imgTwo] andThumb:[MyCommonFunctions saveImageInDocuments:imgOne]];
            [defaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"getArticlesOffline"];
            [defaults synchronize];
        }

    }];
```

Comment: Describe the problem in more detail. Which views? How do you know it has anything to do with AF?

Comment: when i call this function it takes loading continusly and UI freeze but i want UI should be set free

Comment: Not sure that this will solve your problem entirely, but it may help the transition delay if you move your viewDidLoad getArticles call to viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not AF, it's that at the end of that process you call `dataWithContentsOfURL` twice and this runs directly on the main thread to download some images. You need to move that download to a background thread.

Comment: actually i used dataWithContentsOfURL for first image and second for thumb.